# How can I undo a Subversion (svn) merge without reverting?

Tags: svn

While trying to help a coworker figure out where some unit tests went bad in the svn history, I hastily reverse merged a commit that I thought might have been the problem into his working copy:

```
 svn merge -c -1234 .
```

then asked, "wait... you're working copy was clean right?". Unfortunately not.  So a quick revert was not a good option. I tried to undo it cleanly (`svn merge -c 1234`) but nothing happened. Luckily he knew exactly which files were changed so we made a patch, reverted all modified files, and applied the patch.  However, I'm wondering if there was a cleaner way to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original idea was almost right. The Subversion way to do this would have been

```
svn merge -c 1234 . --ignore-ancestry
```

to re-apply the reverse-merged commit.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the reason `svn merge -c 1234` did not work was we were already beyond revision 1234, so svn saw no need to do anything. A solution I tried at my desk later, which worked, was to download a diff of commit 1234, then apply it as a patch. Note that I used `1234` and not `-1234`, which would have been a reverse diff.

```
svn diff -c 1234 > undo.patch
svn patch undo.patch
```

Had I been in the original situation again, this would have undone the reverse merge cleanly while preserving my coworker's changes.